# Hiding peers of parent in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a show/hide content feature work on my page:

```
<div>
    <div class="t">             
        <h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 1</h2>
    </div>

    <section class="title1 title">
        <div class="cat">
            <p>Category 1<span>This is the first category</p>
        </div>

        <div class="cat">
            <p>Category 2<span>This is the second category</p>
        </div>

        <div class="cat">
            <p>Category 3<span>This is the third category</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I think I've kept it pretty simple. Basically, for each section, this markup is going to be repeated. When you click on the link, jquery should show/hide the `section` that is on peer level with the link's container div.

Here's what I've got. It doesn't produce any errors, but it also doesn't hide the sections. It does, however, change the link's text:

```
$(".sh").click(function() {
    var show = ($(this).text() === "+");

    if (show) {
        $(this).parent("div").each("section", function() {$(this).fadeIn(500)});
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent("div").each("section", function() {$(this).fadeOut(500)});
    }
    $(this).text(show ? "-" : "+");
});
```

I think I might be missing something fundamentally important here, so if anyone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong, your help will be greatly appreciated.

TIA :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you're using `.each()`, something like this should work:

```
$(".sh").click(function() {
    var show = ($(this).text() === "+");

    if (show) {
        $(this).parents("div").siblings("section").fadeIn(500);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parents("div").siblings("section").fadeOut(500);
    }
    $(this).text(show ? "-" : "+");
});
```

Comment: I was looking back through the hierarchy and realized that `parent("div")` wasn't giving anything back because the link isn't in the div, it's in the `h2`. Using `.parent().parent().parent("div")` gets the right thing though, but that gives me `Object section has no method 'apply'`

Comment: changed to `$(this).parent().parent("div").siblings("section").fadeOut(500);` and it seems to work :)

Comment: Instead of parent().parent() you could use parents("div") or parents(".t")

Comment: Oops I missed that, I edited my answer to add Jay's suggestion in. Personally, I'd add a class to that div, so you can use `$(this).closest('.container')`. Otherwise your code is tightly coupled with the HTML; change the HTML structure and your javascript breaks. Which is never a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the peers yyou can use `siblings()` to identify them:

```
$('.sh').click(function() {
    var show = ($(this).text() === "+");
     if (show) {
        $(this).parents("div").siblings("section").fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $(this).parents("div").siblings("section").fadeOut(500);
    }
    $(this).text(show ? "-" : "+");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RvHhd/